# Android Studio : Firebase Cloud Messaging Unexpected response code 401

Tags: android, firebase

I would like to send a notification from a device to the other device but it keep on displaying the error message AuthFailureError. Is anyone know why how to solve this problem?

Error Message
E/Volley: [18672] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 401 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

E/Volley: [18672] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 401 for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

E/Result: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

```
public static void SendNotifications(Context applicationContext, String targetToken, String title, String body) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext);
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("to", targetToken);
        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
        notification.put("title", title);
        notification.put("body", body);
        json.put("notification", notification);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postUrl, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("Result", String.valueOf(response));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Result", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                header.put("Content-type", "application/json");
                header.put("authorization", "key=" + fcmServerKey);
                return header;
            }
        };

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
        jsonException.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: try "Authorization" instead of "authorization" in header

Comment: @SreehariK thanks for your reply but it is unworkable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your write

`header.put("Content-type", "application/json");`
`header.put("authorization", "key=" + fcmServerKey);`

**Modify it to be**

`header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");`
`header.put("Authorization", "key=" + fcmServerKey);`

> Content-Type not Content-type and
> Authorization not authorization